# How to implement Smack 4.1.0, ConnectionConfiguration.Builder class?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

There are changes in smack 4.1.0 library, Can someone tell me  how to implement `ConnectionConfiguration.Builder<B extends ConnectionConfiguration.Builder<B,C>,C >` class ?

Comment: Here is a complete implementation of Smack 4.1 API in android at http://marothiatechs.blogspot.in/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat_18.html

Answer (score 7):

If you are connecting to your server via TCP, you can use the `XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration` class. Sample code:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = XMPPConnectionConfiguration
    .builder()
    .setServiceName("example.org");
    .setHost("xmpp1.example.org")
    .setPort(Port)
    .setUsernameAndPassword("user", "password")
    .setCompressionEnabled(false)
    .build();

XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf);
```

Source: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.3/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration.Builder.html

Answer (score -1):

Just check the code of MyXMPP.java [here](http://marothiatechs.blogspot.in/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat_18.html) where complete implementation of Smack 4.1 is explained.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Put some content in your answer instead.

Comment: Link is now dead